# How can i add a timestamp to my script using the linux free command (free | grep mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100.0}')

Tags: linux, scripting, timestamp, free

I just want to add a timestamp to a script output file, and also continue to add output to the same file.

This is the script im using and want to add a timestamp in the output file and want to be able to add entries to the same file over and over again. I would also need to see the timestamp for each entry.

```
free | grep mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100.0}' > free.txt

free | grep mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100.0}' > free.txt
```

The results of the script currently is that i can save the output of a single query but it doesnt have a timestamp, and I dont know how to make it recurring output to the same file for a specific amount of time. Ideally i would make the script run in 5 minute intervals for a week, and then start a new file. I'm not sure if this is even possible. The end result would show a list of free memory percentages over the entire week, so I could see the trends in memory usage and monitor for oversubscription of memory.

Comment: Do you want the time-stamp on the same line, or iterations of timestamps and values each on a line of their own?

Comment: To state it more clearly - I want to adapt the above script to repeat every 5 minutes, add a timestamp to each repeat, add each repeat to the same file. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: And what about my question regarding the output format? :)

Comment: Sorry didnt see it at first - If the timestamp could be on the same line that would be ideal

Answer (score 0):

You **could** conceivably use a loop with a sleep-timer, but I'd recommend using a `cron` job for this.  Put the following in a shell script, and run that via `cron` every 5 minutes.

```
( echo -ne "$( date -Iseconds)\t"; free | awk '/Mem/{print $4/$2 * 100.0}' ) >> free.tx
```

Comment: Fantastic - I will test this out and update the forum with my results tomorrow but this looks like exactly what I needed. Thanks for the quick response, this is much appreciated!

Comment: Much appreciated - I deleted the question after thinking about it for a minute :)

Comment: Here a less garrulous version `date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M"`

Answer (score 0):

```
(date "+%c" | tr -d '\n'; free | awk '/^Mem:/ {print " ", ($4/$2 * 100.0}') > free.txt
```

Or whatever. I hate tr, but it's the fatest way to strip newlinws. Other time formats can be found in date's manpages (not Mac, of course). In that case, google google.

Also you don't need grep here, and you're performing a case-sensitive search anyway, which is bad because the output of free usually creates /^Mem:.*$/

Comment: I dont have enough time in the system to upvote, but thanks for your answer - I see their are various ways to get the output.